# How to have a clone of systems with same data as production servers

Tags: java, middleware, ptc-windchill

We have PLM systems where all our product lifecycle data resides. We want to build services (REST) to let this data accessed by other systems.

The PLM system we are using comes with REST services and we can also build our own on top of that.

These PLM Systems are our production servers and we don't want others to hit these services directly on the production servers. We can rehost other systems with production data but the rehosted system will not always be with live data as production systems.

Any thoughts to solve this problem?

Comment: This is more of a sysadmin type question, but to solve it from a programmers perspective you'd be doing a big ETL operation to re-synch the data on a regular basis. Much easier to do the same task at the system level.  Go bribe your BOFH ...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant PTC Windchill as your PLM system here.

When you're done with rehosting your prod to a new server, you can try the following things.

- Create listeners on your production server for the
  events(statechange,newVersion,checkout,checkin,etc.,) which you think
  you might want to capture when your production data changes.
- Write a REST service with your rehosted server url as the `EndPoint`. At
  the same time you should have a client class in the rehosted server
  to consume.
- In case of new parts or other objects being created in your
  production after rehost, when your listener captures that event, it
  needs to be exported as a jar file to a common folder location using `ixb` api's
  which the other server should have access to.
- You should have a folder watcher in the rehosted server which will be watching that common
  export folder for the new files. Once it finds a new file you can
  import the same using `ixb` into windchill. You can also write a windchill `ScheduleQueue` to do this activity on a particular time interval.

I hope this helps to start.

Comment: Thanks. By creating lister in production - you mean in Windchill itself or create simple listeners? A little bit more explanation will really help here.

Comment: Yes. You need to register a windchill service for listening to events on windchill. You can find the step by step instructions on how to register a service in windchill in this help center [link](http://support.ptc.com/help/windchill/whc/whc_en/index.html#page/Windchill_Help_Center%2FWCListeners_CreatingNonModeledServices.html)

Comment: Do you know if it's applicable for FlexPLM 11.0 also?

Comment: Not sure about that. But you try enabling this property entry from `wt.properties` to `wt.services.verboseEvents=true` and do your actions on flex. Maybe you'll come to know which events are getting triggered in your logs. Then try capture those events from your windchill service class.